# Context in React Natve

Tags: react-native, react-context

So I started learning to react native and I faced the challenge of central data storage. Past in react I used contexts. Is react native supporting it? I haven't learned Redux, but in this case it's not a problem for me.
I've tried to do this in the classic react way

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const LoginTokenContext = createContext();

export const LoginProvider = props => {
    const [loginToken, setLoginToken] = useState( localStorage.getItem('loginToken') );
    const [loginName, setLoginName] = useState( localStorage.getItem('loginName') );

    return(
        <LoginContext.Provider value={ {loginToken, setLoginToken, loginName, setLoginName} }>
            {props.children}
        </LoginContext.Provider>
    );
} ;
```

and it didn't work (may my bad implementation). I've done also some research but couldn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the context to be `LoginTokenContext` and you have used is as `LoginContext.Provider`. There is a typo here.

Change to:

```
<LoginTokenContext.Provider value={ {loginToken, setLoginToken, loginName, setLoginName} }>
    {props.children}
</LoginTokenContext.Provider>
```

Comment: yeah, it definitely was a problem, but still doesn't work.
app component:
`import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,SafeAreaView,StatusBar,TouchableWithoutFeedback,Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import TabNavigator from './routes/drawer';
import LoginProvider from './components/context/LoginContext';
export default function App() {
  
  return(
    <LoginProvider>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <TabNavigator />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </LoginProvider>
  );
}`

Comment: ok it's working, it was just about destructing importing object in 'import Login Provider from...'